# Is it possible for the output of SHA-1 to end in zero bytes?

Tags: python, cryptography, sha1

Is it possible for `sha1` hashes to end with zero bytes?

Python Code

```
hash = haslib.sha1();
hash.update(STRING THAT RESULTS IN ZERO BYTES);
if hash.digest().endswith('\x00\x00\x00'):
....
```

Comment: This property is for SHA-256 actually used in bitcoin mining (although I think BC hashes are tested to start with zero bits, but as either bit is as likely to be 0 that doesn't matter much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since hash function outputs are supposed to be uniformly distributed you have a non-zero chance of getting any supported output. The chance for seeing the last 24 bits (3 byte) as zero is `1.0/(2**24)` or `5.9 * 10-8`. On average you will have to try 2<sup>23</sup> random strings to find one with this property. Since hashing is pretty fast, this shouldn't take longer than a couple of minutes (although, Python might be a bit slow in general).

Comment: Thank you! The only possibility to find a matching hash is brute forcing.. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You would have to brute-force your way to that result.

Comment: Running a simple (32 bit) counter and hashing that should be enough to find such a hash. Again, that's what BC does.